# How to create array without using NSArray , NSDictionary, NSSet. Want to create array ,add elements and delete elements does this make sense?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

How can I create an array without using `NSArray` , `NSDictionary`, `NSSet` and even `NSMutableArray`, `NSMutableDictionary`? I want to create an array, add elements and delete elements using Objective-C in Xcode.

My main goal is to add elements and delete them by giving objectAtIndex and also to display the number of elements in the array.

```
int n[ 10 ]; /* n is an array of 10 integers */
int i,j;

/* initialize elements of array n to 0 */
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    n[ i ] = i + 101; /* set element at location i to i + 100 */
}

/* output each array element's value */
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
{
    printf("Element[%d] = %d\n", j, n[j] );
}

printf("Number of Elements in Array %lu",sizeof(n) / sizeof(int));


//    /* loop for the deletion  */
int loc = 5,num = 10;
printf("\nRemove  Element[%d] from Array:",loc);
while (loc < num) {
    n[loc - 1] = n[loc];
    loc++;
}
num--;  // No of elements reduced by 1

//Print Array
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    printf("\n %d", n[i]);

NSLog(@"Count of Array %d",num);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this - is there a specific reason?

Comment: So, you're asking how to code an array-like container that can grow and shrink as necessary, support random access, in obj-c, but without using any obj-c container types?

Comment: stack overflow is no coding service.

Comment: You are asking how to duplicate `NSMutableArray`.  Short answer: "By writing a ton of code." This is what's known in the business as a "solved problem." Why do you want to go to a great deal of work to do something that is already offered by the OS? This smells like a school assignment to me.

Comment: You can always use a C array.

Comment: Except a C array doesn't resize itself, doesn't support insertion/deletion, etc.

Comment: @DuncanC: That means the poor kid has to write code. Poor little Nikii.

Comment: Yes you can say its school assignment ! And I'm literally sucked up. I don't find a way to solve this problem without using collection class. But I have been asked to to write a create a array and insert objects and delete it without using  foundation  class.  What I did is :

Comment: //    /* loop for the deletion  */
    int loc = 5,num = 10;
    printf("\nRemove  Element[%d] from Array:",loc);
    while (loc < num) {
        n[loc - 1] = n[loc];
        loc++;
    }
    num--;  // No of elements reduced by 1
    
    //Print Array
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("\n %d", n[i]);
    
    NSLog(@"Count of Array %d",num);  so do u think is this a solution ?

Comment: I have been asked to put above functionality in Objective c Methods: That is First method : -(void)addObjects :(id)Object; Second -( void )removeObjectAtIndex , Third -(NSInterger)getCountOfArray; Can you guys help me how to fit the above functionality in these methods?

Comment: I need your help guys! :) please sort this for me.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, there are ways to do this without using any of the previously mentioned types/structures, but i guess the question is WHY? NSMutableArray is exactly what you need I would think.
but to get to your question just define the array: e.g.

```
NSString *aString[20];
```

But, you would be responsible for adding to the array and deleting from the array, which is expensive in terms of time and prone to coding errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::vector in C++. You can use Swift Array.

Comment: I m not suppose to use swift array either! (Sorry problem statement defines this !) So can't help I have to use Basic c logic in Xcode.